# Public access to server's phpSysInfo - is it safe?

Tags: php, linux, security

Is it generally safe to not restrict the access to "phpsysinfo" system information page of a linux server? There are some information on the server software, linux distro running and HDDs (and that could be potentionally helpful if someone wanted to hack the system), but is the cod of phpSysInfo safe? Would you advise to limit the access?

Comment: Restrict access to who? On the command line? On a web page?

Comment: [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) is soooo much better if usefull stats is what your after...

Comment: @Pekka on the webpage for non-administrators, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, nothing is 100% safe. For this reason I would restrict access to phpSysInfo to the people who need it.

I good security tip : Always restrict access to only the people who need the corresponding functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I'll then make it password-protected.

Answer (score 2):

Came back after years to further clarify this issue. While Dwarth's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850871/1306158) is correct in the general case, PHPSysInfo is outright *dangerous* in some situations.

It may be not so obvious - yes, showing hardware info can be considered unsafe already, but it may be fine in many situations. However since PHPSysInfo shows *full mtab output* it also includes stuff like *mounted disks' passwords* if you have any.

You may want to avoid having that in the first place but if you can't anything that shows mounted devices in full will leak this info.